# What is the usage of global:: keyword in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax, keyword

What is the usage of `global::` keyword in C#? When must we use this keyword?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Technically, `global` is not a keyword: it's a so-called "contextual keyword". These have special meaning only in a limited program context and can be used as identifiers outside that context.

`global` can and should be used whenever there's ambiguity or whenever a member is hidden. From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d(VS.80).aspx):

```
class TestApp
{
    // Define a new class called 'System' to cause problems.
    public class System { }

    // Define a constant called 'Console' to cause more problems.
    const int Console = 7;
    const int number = 66;

    static void Main()
    {
        // Error  Accesses TestApp.Console
        Console.WriteLine(number);
        // Error either
        System.Console.WriteLine(number);
        // This, however, is fine
        global::System.Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```

Note, however, that `global` doesn't work when no namespace is specified for the type:

```
// See: no namespace here
public static class System
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // "System" doesn't have a namespace, so this
        // will refer to this class!
        global::System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```