# namespace being shadowed

Tags: c#, namespaces

so I have a library `Mine.SuperFun` which calls stuff in the library SuperFun whose main namespace is `SuperFun`. The problem i'm having is that i can't address classes or basically anything in the SuperFun library inside classes in the `Mine.SuperFun.XyZFoo` namespaces

The only way to address them i have is doing stuff like:

```
using SuperFun_NiceClass = SuperFun.NiceClass;

using Mine.SuperFun {

...

SuperFun_NiceClass.DoStuff()
```

is there something i can do (besides changing the namespace in Mine library) to be able to address those classes directly?

Comment: no, i can't fully qualify them.. that is the problem

Comment: Excellent question... I've bumped into this a few times... and just did what you did. global:: is nice!  Thanks lurscher for posting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `global` contextual keyword

[What is the usage of global:: keyword in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340355/what-is-the-usage-of-global-keyword-in-c)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx

```
namespace Mine.SuperFun
{
    public class My { public int a; }
}

namespace SuperFun
{
    public class Theirs { public int a; }
}

namespace SomeProgram
{
    public class Program
    {
        SuperFun.Theirs theirs;
        global::Mine.SuperFun.My mine;
    }
}
```